# Specify a prefered character for in-line math linebreak?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I'm currently writing my phd thesis and I'm using some statistical formula like the following.

> [$F(1,14)=8.93,p<.01,\etacarre=.37$]

When multiple formula of this kind are present, there might be some break at undesired location : for instance just after an equal sign.

Is there a possibility to tell latex to favor break at specific locations, in math in-line mode, like at commas, just before the `p`, or just before the `\etacarre` ?

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{book}

% GENERAL %

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Fonte
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Eta carre généralisé %%
\newcommand{\etacarre}{\widehat{\eta}^{2}_{G}}

\begin{document}
[$F(1,14)=8.93,p<.01,\etacarre=.37$] Test test test test test Test test test test test Test test test test test Test test test test test Test test test  [$F(1,14)=8.93,p<.01,\etacarre=.37$] Test test test test test Test [$F(1,14)=8.93,p<.01,\etacarre=.37$]
\end{document}
```

Which leads to :

[image]

EDIT : I already know about local solutions, like hyphen-space, `\mbox`, or the `\allowbreak`. But, actually I'm looking for a global solution, so I do not have to modify each and every of the formulas that are already written.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) `\allowbreak` is your friend, LaTeX is not allowed to break a line after comma in math mode, unless you tell it is allowed: `[$F(1,14)=8.93,\allowbreak p<.01,  \allowbreak \etacarre=.37$] `

Comment: And to preclude a break, you can place the unbreakable stuff in a box, `$\mbox{$F(1,14)=8.93$},p<.01,\etacarre=.37$`

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. I also know the hyphen-space solution. But, actually, I'm looking for a wide-document solution, so I do not have to modify each and every of the formula I have already written (I'll make an edit).

Comment: the built in places are exactly the places you said that you didn't want to break, after a binary operator or after a relation, tex will not break in math mode except those places or at an explicit `\penalty`

Comment: Thanks, but if you take a look at my MWE, you will see that latex seems to break randomly, after the =, or the <. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: that isn't random they are exactly the places that it allows breaking, after = and after relations like <  you can prevent linebreaks there (set `\binoppenalty` and `\relpenalty` to 10000 but then tex will not break inline math at all except at explicit `\penalty` that you add.

Comment: Uhm... so if I understand well, there's no problem here. I thought it would be more pleasant not to have some math relations broken into two parts, though that's an other question.

Comment: different countries have different conventions but tex isn't very configurable here: it tries not to break math at all but if it does break it considers breaking after = the best place to do that (given the default value of `\relpenalty`)